# Non-triviality of map $S^{24} \longrightarrow S^{21} \longrightarrow Sp(3)$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, gn.general-topology, homotopy-theory, lie-groups

Let $\theta$ be the generator of $\pi_{21}(Sp(3))\cong \mathbb{Z}_3$, (localized at 3).
How to show the composition
$$S^{24}\longrightarrow S^{21}\overset{\theta}\longrightarrow Sp(3)$$
is non-trivial (3-loca).

Comment: A little bit of background/motivation for the question can help...

Comment: We have, 3-Local, $\pi_{24}(S^{21})\cong \mathbb{Z}_3$ and also $\pi_{24}(Sp(3))\cong \mathbb{Z}_3$. Probably by a contradiction or Toda brackets, we can show it.

Comment: How is $\theta$ detected? If you know the answer then some cohomology operation on higher order may do the job!